# How to get the absolute path of a file when given a relative or absolute path and the absolute path it is relative to

Tags: java, file

Let's say I have an absolute 'base' path:

```
/home/someone/dir1/dir2/
```

The user can pass me a new path, that can either be absolute or relative to base path, so the following would both be valid:

```
..
/home/someone/dir1/
```

How do I get java to give me the correct absolute path ie for both these cases:

```
/home/someone/dir1/
```

and do this in a platform-independent way?

I tried the following:

```
File resolvedFile = new File((new File(basePath).toURI().resolve(new File(newPath).toURI())));
```

However, where newPath was relative, newFile(newPath) resolves it automatically against the current working directory, rather than the basePath I want to supply.

Any thoughts?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question..

Seems like it can be done in java 7 using Path:

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/home/joe/foo");
// Result is /home/joe/foo/bar
System.out.format("%s%n", p1.resolve("bar"));
```

Since I can't get java 7 for my mac 10.5.8, I'm going with something like (NB NOT THOROUGHLY TESTED!):

`static String getAbsolutePath(String basePath, String relativeOrAbsolutePath) throws IOException {`

```
    boolean isAbsolute = false;
    File relativeOrAbsoluteFile = new File(relativeOrAbsolutePath);

    if (relativeOrAbsoluteFile.isAbsolute()){
        isAbsolute = true;
    }

    if (isAbsolute){
        return relativeOrAbsolutePath;
    }
    else {
        File absoluteFile = new File(basePath, relativeOrAbsolutePath);
        return absoluteFile.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`File#getCanonicalPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29)

From the JavaDocs:

> Returns the canonical pathname string of this abstract pathname. A
>   canonical pathname is both absolute and unique. The precise definition
>   of canonical form is system-dependent. This method first converts this
>   pathname to absolute form if necessary, as if by invoking the
>   getAbsolutePath() method, and then maps it to its unique form in a
>   system-dependent way. This typically involves removing redundant names
>   such as "." and ".." from the pathname, resolving symbolic links (on
>   UNIX platforms), and converting drive letters to a standard case (on
>   Microsoft Windows platforms).
>
> Every pathname that denotes an existing file or directory has a unique
>   canonical form. Every pathname that denotes a nonexistent file or
>   directory also has a unique canonical form. The canonical form of the
>   pathname of a nonexistent file or directory may be different from the
>   canonical form of the same pathname after the file or directory is
>   created. Similarly, the canonical form of the pathname of an existing
>   file or directory may be different from the canonical form of the same
>   pathname after the file or directory is deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately that resolves the relative path against the current working directory. I don't see a way of supplying a path to which the relative path is relative.

Comment: A relative path is, well, relative from your current position. Without an additional context, I'm not sure how you could possible be able to achieve what you want

Comment: The additional context is the 'base' path. It can be done in java 7 with Path, and I think my answer below works for java 6 and below.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code.

System.setProperty("user.dir", "your_base_path")

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to mention that this needs to work in a multi-threaded environment, so setting a system property won't work.. Thanks for the answer though..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works outside of my setup (windows platform, JRE 1.6.x)

but the following worked like a trick:

```
File path = new File(relativeOrAbsoluteGoldpath);
absolutePath = path.getCanonicalPath();
```

where `relativeOrAbsoluteGoldpath` is an arbitrary path name that may or may not be relative.